# No subscribers for newsletter on multiple stores

Tags: newsletter, newsletter-subscriber, magento2.3.2

We have 3 stores on one domain.

When I try to add a new subcriber, with a non customer mail, the subscriber is NOT added to the newsletter list.

I can go to the customer section and a a existing customer to the newsletter list. But not from the frontend. Is it because we have more that one store?

Any idea?

Answer (score 1):

Please check in admin newsletter configuration for the guest user is set YES. This allows for all users from front site to subscribe

> Stores >> Customers >> Newsletter
>
> Subscription option >> Allow Guest Subscription = YES

Comment: That is allready set to YES